# "data-column-id" in bootstrap table with conditions

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I want to apply conditions on `data-column-id` which is being fetched from `php` code.Is this possible to do something like this?

```
if(data-column-id)==0{
data-column-id="ordinary";
}else{
data-column-id="ordinary";
}// i want this for cat_type
```

**table**

```
<table id="categories_grid" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped" data-toggle="bootgrid">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-column-id="cat_id" data-type="numeric" data-identifier="true">CatID</th>
                <th data-column-id="cat_name">Name</th>
                <th data-column-id="cat_type">Type</th>
                <th data-column-id="commands" data-formatter="commands" data-sortable="false">Commands</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
 </table>
```

**AJAX**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        var grid = $("#categories_grid").bootgrid({

            ajax: true,
            rowSelect: true,
            post: function ()
            {
                /* To accumulate custom parameter with the request object */
                return {
                    id: "b0df282a-0d67-40e5-8558-c9e93b7befed"

                };
            },

            url: "response_categories.php",
            formatters: {
                "commands": function(column, row)
                {
                    return "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-default command-edit\" data-row-id=\"" + row.cat_id + "\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-edit\"></span></button> " +
                        "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-default command-delete\" data-row-id=\"" + row.cat_id + "\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-trash\"></span></button>";
                }
               /* "type":function (column,row) {
                    if(row.cat_type == 0)
                    {
                        return "ordinary";
                    }
                    else
                        return "special";

                }*/
            }
        }).on("loaded.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function()
```

Comment: update your question to include the code that generates the tbody

Comment: @MackProgramsAlot i have updated have a look

Comment: console log the dom element and ensure that you're actually getting an object

Comment: Done thanks  alot :)

Comment: no problem thanks for working with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A check like this, and the setting of the data attribute can be done via JavaScript. Here I will be using jQuery.

Given a DOM element:

```
<th id='test_id' data-column-id="cat_id" data-type="numeric" data-identifier="true">CatID</th>
```

We can select it, and its data attributes as such. In order to select it more easily and for example purposes I've added an id to the table header above. (test_id)

```
var column_id = $('#test_id').data('column-id');
```

Now that we have its value we can perform the check you wish:

```
if(column_id == 0){
    // logic
}else{
    // logic
}
```

In order to set a data attribute you simply do the following:

```
$('#test_id').data('column-id', 'some value');
```

Following this statement your DOM element becomes:

```
<th id='test_id' data-column-id="some value" data-type="numeric" data-identifier="true">CatID</th>
```

Comment: I tried your code and works in `<thead>` only. It is not displaying any value in `<tbody>`

Comment: you need to update the selector appropriately. My answer is intended to teach you how to, you need to figure out how my answer relates to your problem.

Comment: be sure you wait until the document has loaded as well. $(document).ready(function(){

});

Comment: Yes i have do the same thing but it's not working for me

Comment: update the question to include the code that generates the tbody please